# Between two options, which does "former" refer to and which does "latter"?

Tags: difference, meaning

For example:

> James was talking to Karl, the former being much smarter than the latter.

Is James the *former* or the *latter*? What is the rule?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was asked here, when the answer is so [easily and readily found](https://www.google.com/search?q=former+and+latter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t).

Comment: @J.R. It's asked here because I don't want to have to keep referring to a dictionary every time I want to know whether to use *former* or *latter*. If I know the rule then that is a lot easier to remember than some dictionary definition.

Comment: If that's the case, then I think your question would have been much improved had you elaborated about how you often confuse the two, and are looking for a handy, memorable way to keep the two straight. As it is, you've simply asked us to clarify something very basic. Notice, too, that the results I linked to (like [this one](http://www.uhv.edu/ac/newsletters/writing/grammartip2007.10.31.htm) and [this one](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/former-or-latter.aspx)) are **not** dictionary definitions, but easily found mnemonic tricks with detailed explanations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Basically](http://www.uhv.edu/ac/newsletters/writing/grammartip2007.10.31.htm): "former" = "first item in a pair", "latter" = "second item in a pair".

So, in your case, "the former" is James, while "the latter" is Karl.

Answer (score 18):

The mnemonic I learned in school was (F)ormer is (F)irst and (L)atter is (L)ast, so James is the former and Karl is the latter.

Answer (score 4):

"Former" comes before, and "latter" comes later.

Comment: Except when you're asking about the _latter_ and the _former_, in which case the former comes later, and the latter comes before. ;^)

Comment: @J.R. -- +1 for the wink.  I was, of course, trying to tie the pronunciations, but you've got me on the positioning aspect.